# Blackberry 10 Mobile Application Error (Google Maps API)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I am trying to use the google map api with

```
  script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
```

But when I run my app in my blackberry 10 I get this error:

```
  Access to "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" not allowed
```

Solution:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Blackberry-10-Error-Google-Maps-API/m-p/2284235/highlight/false

Comment: This is a very good question. First and foremost what IDE are you developing this Blackberry App with ? This will help me troubleshoot what could be causing your compilation error.

Comment: I am using BB10 webworks sdk

Comment: Could you post your entire code so that I can verify the syntax. So far it appears that the code may not be set to a public function, and it may be in an internal function or private function.

Comment: okies, thanks and give me a minute

Comment: Actually it works when I run it in ripple. and do you want to see the index.html file or the function where i use the google map api?

Comment: index.html : http://pastebin.com/Rs8T07ki
actual function: http://pastebin.com/iAyHT7mL

Comment: This is striking to me as a syntax error.  Check your syntax.  I will also check the syntax and let you know what I find.

Comment: I been stuck for hours now, could it be a problem caused when packaging?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually caused because the domain is not white-listed in the config.xml.  You'll need to add the following for any domains you plan on sending requests to.

For example...

```
<access uri="*" subdomains="true" />
<access uri="http://google.com" subdomains="true" />
```

If you take a look at the sample app I created, it should also help point you in the right direction.  https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/Maps